# Find typescript class usages programmatically

Tags: typescript, dependencies

I want to find all the modules that import `MyClass` from `moduleA`.

Is there a npm module that can show the usages, similar how IDEs are showing them?

The closest ones I've found were [madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge) and [dependency-cruiser](https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser) but they don't show the exact usage of `MyClass` only dependencies on the `moduleA`.

Comment: I just checked the discussions of both libraries, indeed they dont offer class based dep usage preview. I would guess it is because JS (and TS) strongly relays on modules and JS is also not a class based language..

Answer (score 0):

While i'm searching for an answer I had to prototype a solution for my needs. https://github.com/vladimirnani/typescript-class-usage-graph

Its not optimal but at least solves it for now.